# Putting 2 jpanels in borderlayout

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to put 2 JPanels in borderLayout. Such that, one JPanel will be of size pane1(600,600)and the other one would be pane2(200,600). I am hoping to pack them such that the big one would be on the left and other one would be on right. 
I am setting the size of each jpane but it looks like both of them occupy the complete space and kind of overlap on each other.

I am a complete newbie here and have no clue what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated. 
`JFrame frame = new JFrame("Simple Graph");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        int pane1_width = FRAME_WIDTH-200;//800-200
        Pane1 myPlots = new Pane1(graph_panel_size, FRAME_HEIGHT);

        frame.add(myPlots);
        Pane2 simpleInfo = new Pane2(200,FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.add(simpleInfo);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);`

This is a base frame class. For JPanel

`public Pane2(int width,int height){

        this.setSize(width,height);
        Border blackline = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("ola");
        this.setBorder(blackline);`

The other panel also has similar constructor. But both the Jpanels overlap each other and I cant place them separately.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `setSize()`. When using `LayoutManager`'s (which you should absolutely always do), using `setSize/setBounds/setLocation` is completely useless.

Additionnaly, calling `setPreferredSize()/setMinimumSize/setMaximumSize` is not recommended and can be counterproductive.

Either your component have a good reason to have a given size (because you are doing custom painting, for example), then you should override `getPreferredSize`, or you simply don't have to do anything, and only use an appropriate `LayoutManager`.

You can also [check out the tutorial on LayoutManager of Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

See this example with overrides of `getPreferredSize()`:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestCustomPainting {

    private static class MyTriangle extends JPanel {

        private final int width;
        private final int height;

        public MyTriangle(int width, int height) {
            this.width = width;
            this.height = height;
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(width, height);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
            g.fillPolygon(new int[] { 0, getWidth(), 0 }, new int[] { 0, 0, getHeight() }, 3);
        }

    }

    protected static void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("test");
        frame.add(new MyTriangle(200, 45), BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(new MyTriangle(85, 600), BorderLayout.WEST);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                initUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

NB: I must admit, there are more interesting to paint :-)

Comment: Hey Thanks. :) And in the meantime I found another link on stackoverflow which explained getPreferredSize(). So, I am new to any kind of GUI programming. Coming from systems background(Or for anyone coming from any programming background) and calling getPreferredSize() instead of setPreferredSize() sounds completely counterintentive. Other than historical screw ups is there any reason to have setPreferredSize(). Thanks